# How can I eliminate the choice between Windows and Ubuntu every time I boot?

Tags: grub2, wubi

After making a bootable disk of Ubuntu 13.04, I opened it from windows 8 and ran `wubi.exe`. Then I was presented with three options...

1. Reboot now
2. Reboot later
3. Help me boot from disk

I selected choice no. 3, but the installation didn't run properly.

From that point on, whenever Windows boots, it shows the Windows Boot Manager with the choice between *Windows* and *Ubuntu*.

I want to get rid of this menu and want to use only Windows 8 or both.

How is it possible.....please help me...

Comment: You have two problems. One is you want to remove the menu and have the ability to use either Windows or both Windows and Ubuntu. I believe you may have to have a menu to use both OSs.

Answer (score 2):

Go to *Control Panel*, *Add/remove programs*, double click on *Ubuntu*

Although Wubi is well known to install Ubuntu *inside* Windows, it also contains a helper menu if you open an Ubuntu DVD in Windows. It does **not** offer to install inside Windows by default anymore.

The first option (Reboot) simply reboots the computer.
The second option does nothing (you will reboot later).

These two seemingly useless options are just to let you know that you should boot from the DVD (not use it while Windows is running).

The third option (Help me Boot) actually installs something like the normal Wubi so that you can boot the CD via the hard drive, not using `BIOS` functions. This is mostly unnecessary except perhaps for very old computers or users who can't get their PCs to boot from a DVD/CD. You **still** need to have the DVD in the drive - so it doesn't remove the need for it (can't be used with just the ISO).

Since you have Windows 8, you may have `UEFI` (if it came preinstalled with Windows 8) - in which case, the CD Boot helper will not work.